# Comment notification special characters

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, languages, comment-replies

It was pointed out to me today that I don't need to copy and paste the Æ in "Æther" to respond to her comments, the system accepts "Aether" as well.

I'm curious to know if this is a special case for the Æ character, or if the comment notification system has a unicode (or other character set) translation table to support this feature.

"ü" would be another character, for instance, that might be translated to the equivalent english character. (as well as the o and a umlauts)

Not asking for a change, just want to make sure I'm not doing unnecessary work when replying to comments by understanding the system.  My search-fu is weak, as I was unable to find a prior discussion on this...

Comment: I see this is also implemented in the user search box - wonder which came first...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this last week (and mentioned it in an off-topic comment); I'm not sure if it was recently added or it existed all along. I've used this name for a few months, minus the week-long interregnum earlier this month when I was Thingadongdong.

Comment: @Æther - Long live thingadongdong!

Comment: Convenience link: [the off-topic comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38059/131713) that @Ether mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like [SQL Server Collation](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/15/1469885.aspx) at work. Go Stack Overflow team; the discovery of this makes my life (and I'm sure many others') much easier!

Comment: Now you left me wondering if PostgreSQL or MySQL has something similar... If only there were a site to make a technical question like that one...

Comment: Wow, very interesting!

Comment: @The Big: There is. It's http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx. Alex seems to love it when people do that!