# @Joerg works for Jörg W Mittag?

Tags: discussion, comment-replies, unicode

Does changing an umlauted letter into two letters work for @ comment replies, for example `@Joerg`?

Or do I have to do `@Jorg`, like in [@Peter works for Péter Török?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48968/peter-works-for-peter-torok) and unlike `Æ` changing to `ae` in [Comment notification special characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38288/comment-notification-special-characters)?

Comment: Sounds like you’re asking whether they use the Unicode Collation Algorithm’s primary strength comparison. That way things like "ø" and "o" count as the same, "æ" counts as "ae", etc. That works without locales, but to get "ä" to go to "ae" or "ö" to go to "oe", you would need to be in the German locale, which wouldn’t work well for a non-German forum; similarly for "å" going to "aa" and other locale-specific conventions. **And** if it were a Spanish forum, then "ñ" would *not* go to "n", as it normally does.

Comment: @tchrist: Where would "ñ" go? Would it [go to eleven](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89166/does-non-ascii-character-support-go-to-eleven)?

Comment: In the Spanish locale (which we aren't using), "ñ" collates after "n" but before "o". In the default, however, it is the same as the letter "n".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ("òóôõöøo".Contains(s))
{
    return "o";
}
```

From [Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696)

So you must do `@Jorg`.

Comment: Well that's good to know.  Though personally, I try to just copy the first part of the name and use that in my @ comments.

Comment: @Jeff: I used to do that. Too much work, because it involves using a mouse.

Answer (score 2):

The engine doesn't have specific support for transliteration of German names.

@-replies are hard to get right manually, especially with names containing characters that aren't on your keyboard or names that are hard to read¹. Fortunately there's a script for that:

- [SE Modifications — Username autocomplete in comments, inline revision source, and utility links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an) for the keyboard aficionados.
- [“Reply” links on comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) if your mouse hand never leaves your mouse.

¹  <sub>My name is all ASCII letters, but back when `@` replies required 4 characters, I noticed several `@Giles` replies, and probably missed many more.</sub>