# Wrong asciification of name in profile address

Tags: support, display-names

When signing up the system has created a profile address for my profile that ends in "bjorn-hohrmann". This rendering of my name is incorrect and offensive.

There are some languages that asciify "ö" as "o", several Scandinavian ones for instance, but I am German where the "proper" transliteration is "oe". There does not seem to be an option to correct this (I haven't tried changing the names in my profile, as I do not know if that would have any effect and I am not keen to put "oe" in there anyway).

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Why is this offensive? (And for your information: yes, changing your name to explicitly use `oe` rather than `ö` would change the slug in the URL.)

Comment: How will the code know the difference between the German `ö` and the Scandinavian `ö`?

Comment: It's like calling me "Burn Herman" which I can tolerate when spoken as pronouncing foreign names is hard, but this is a computer doing it. Should I edit this into a feature request then so the "slug" can be set independently (perhaps with a language/region setting for the transliteration)?

Comment: By the way: note that [in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020), one could use both `@Björn`, `@björn` and `@bjorn` to send you a notification, [but not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg-w-mittag) `@bjoern`. If one could choose their own ASCII name, then which form should people use when replying in comments?

Comment: It's not perfect, but seeing as it's just the slug, I don't agree it's a big problem.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is likely to be fixed, given that to do it there would have to be a ‘what culture does your name come from’ option. And then you'd need the same option for everything that might ever go in a URL, and most users wouldn't want to cope with that added complexity.

I think the ‘best’ solution—but one that would need quite a lot of work to support across everywhere URIs work—would be to do what eg. Wikipedia does, and use [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier)s, so that non-ASCII characters can be included in the slug. So use:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163578/bj%C3%B6rn-h%C3%B6hrmann
```

which would be displayed in the address bar of modern browsers as:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/163578/björn-höhrmann
```

Comment: I don't think the "what culture does your name come from" option is as far fetched as you're making out. It's called localisation, and most mature software applications make use of it for exactly these purposes. When you install Mac OS X for the first time (for example) it asks you to pick a locale. This is one of the reasons why.

Comment: We know what that gets us! http://stackoverflow.com/z%CD%8A%CC%93%CD%A3%CD%A4%CD%ACa%CC%93%CC%83%CD%AAl%CD%A7%CD%8B%CC%89%CD%9B%CC%8Bg%CD%AF%CD%8B%CD%AFo%CC%93%CD%92